# How to configure Vaadin project to use Vaadin-spring-boot-starter with latest Vaadin framework

Tags: maven, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin4spring

I have defined my project based on latest Vaadin Spring boot starter version 2.0.1 as below.
I want to use the latest Vaadin framework version 8.1.0.rc2 (released today) for using Tree and new drag and drop features. Is it possible to keep spring boot version but use new Vaadin feature in Maven?

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <vaadin.version>8.1.0.rc2</vaadin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gdl2</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdl2</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openehr.adl2-core</groupId>
        <artifactId>adl-parser</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I should change the repository because I want to use a prerelease version.  To do this the below lines should be added to repository in pom file:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
        <name>Vaadin Pre-releases</name>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
        <name>Vaadin Pre-releases</name>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Except this the below dependencies should be added:

```
<!-- ===============================Spring dependency======================================= -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- ============================Vaadin dependencies=============================== -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The last thing is version property:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <vaadin.version>8.1.0.rc2</vaadin.version>
</properties>
```